# Trigger when a user clicks on a link

Tags: navigation, rules

I have a menu listing different links and on some of the links, I want to trigger a notification to the User. I'm working on drupal 7. Also please let me know what modules I would need in the process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into the [Rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules)? It's great for making conditional actions and can do stuff like sending out mails.

Comment: I don't see a option inside the rules interface for an action when the user clicks on a link, am i missing something ? or should i be writing custom code ?

Comment: You want to look at the 'user is going to view a page' rule

Comment: This event does not appear in drupal 7. Any idea why?

Comment: Use "Drupal is initialising" as the trigger event and then add a Data comparison condition to test the path. That should get you the same functionality as 'user is going to view a page'.

Answer (score 1):

Just if someone come across it and not able to solve.

Steps:

Download the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module

1. Go to `admin/config/workflow/rules`
2. Create a rule
3. Event: Drupal is initializing
4. Condition: Data comparison:

   - Data to compare :[site:current-page:url]
   - Operator: equals
   - Data value: any URL you want
5. Action: page redirect / popup load / send email / etc...

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on the above for anyone that finds this post, I achieved this following danbohea's directions and using Text comparison as the condition

Parameter: Text: [site:current-page:url], Matching text: home

Comment: Hello, can you please post above with steps, right now it is not constructive.